# How do I use PHP string interpolation and square brackets in a MySQL regexp?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

In my query I have:

```php
$search .= "and title REGEXP '[[:<:]]$q[[:>:]]' ";
```

Which produces the following error in the Apache error log:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

I tried putting {} around it, but that didn't work either.

Thank you.

Comment: Escape the dollar sign with a backslash. PHP is trying to interpret it as a variable. Or better yet, use a prepared statement and you don't have to worry about these things.

Comment: Prepared statements are imperative here. This is asking for serious problems.

Comment: @tadman, what do you mean serious problems?

Comment: I solved it by using this code prior to the actual query:  $regexpVariable = "[[:<:]]" . $q . "[[:>:]]";

Comment: @NestMan Look at what a [tool like this](http://sqlmap.org) can do to your site if you make a mistake of this magnitude. It's not a good list of things.

Comment: I reopened this because the focus of the "dup" had nothing to do with the solution needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add braces:  `$search .= "and title REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$q}[[:>:]]'";` -- otherwise it thinks you are referencing the $q array.

PHP allows array lookups in strings, such as "... `$q[...]` ..."  It also allows expresssions:  `"... {$a+$b} ..."` *if* you add the braces.  Putting those together solves this problem.